# How to add call back function for this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wondered what is the most easy way to add call back function to the function below:

```
<script>
$(document).on('focus', '#inputbox', function(e) {

    $( this).contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap("<span class='new'></span>");
//I tried add function here but it would execute infinite times.

});
</script>
```

Comment: What you want to do ? And when ?

Comment: can you create a fiddle of it.

Comment: You can try `promise`.

Answer (score 0):

The same you already try, but skip all redundant calls for cb

```
<script>
function cb() { alert('Wow!'); }
(function() {
var timer;
var delay = 1000; // call cb delay
$(document).on('focus', '#inputbox', function(e) {

    $( this).contents().filter(function() {
      return this.nodeType === 3;
    }).wrap("<span class='new'></span>");
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(cb, delay);
});
})();
</script>
```

Comment: Using setTimeout is more of a patchwork. You should rather use `promise`

Comment: @Rajesh I can create code with promises, but 1) promise can chane it's value only once, 2) that code will use setTimeout